# Tag EBS volume created by a launch_template and autoscaling group via Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

How do we make the launch_template resource created by terraform, add tags to the EBS volume created and which is attached to the used AMI ?

Comment: Please before you vote to close the topic, this is a very important question that needs to be answered on stackoverflow

Comment: Is the answer below not programmatic for you ? it's terraform !! it's infrastracture as code tool

Comment: well programmers are today concerned about how to create their own infrastructure. every thing is programming right now. no difference anymore okay. thanks

Comment: I don't agree. Ok let's say you are right. What server am I asking about here? what network issue? none, it's about how programmatically tag a volume. Okay alright. Plus, this is not the first time someone asks a question about Amazon Web services. There are tones of AWS questions on stackoverflow

Comment: Adrian, Terraform is a declarative language. This question absolutely does belong here. We get that you dont think so, but it's an opinion. Not a fact.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `tag_specifications` with `resource_type` of `volume`.

```
resource "aws_launch_template" "foo" {
  name = "foo"

  block_device_mappings {
    device_name = "/dev/sda1"

    ebs {
      volume_size = 20
    }
  }

  image_id = "ami-test"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  key_name = "test"

  tag_specifications {
    resource_type = "instance"

    tags = {
      Name = "test"
    }
  }

  tag_specifications {
    resource_type = "volume"

    tags = {
      Name = "test"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: how do you tag a particular mapping, in case you have multiple ones?